# Custom Hook and cascading dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown, cascading

I'm new to react and I'm learning by doing. Right now I'm stacked on using a custom Hook to share logic among components.

here is the logic inside the custom Hook

```
const useDropDownLogic = () => {
    const { menu } = useContext(MenuContext)
    const brand = [...new Set(menu.map(i => i.brand))]
    const [category, setCategory] = useState([])

    const brandChange = (e) => {
        const { type, textContent } = e.target
        setCategory([...new Set(menu.filter(i => i.[type] == textContent).map(i => i.category))])}

    return {
        brandChange, 
        brand, 
        category
    }
}
 
export default useDropDownLogic;
```

here is the first component consuming the custom Hook

```
const DropDownBrand = () => {
  const {brandChange, brand} = useDropDownLogic();
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectOutsideClick(dropdownRef, false);
  const onClick = () => setIsActive(!isActive)

  return (
    <div id="dropdownbrand">
      <div className="menu-container menu-brand">
        <label className = 'nav-label'>Select a Brand</label>
        <button onClick={onClick} className="menu-trigger brand-btn">
        <i className="fas fa-chevron-down fa-2x drop-arrow"></i>
        </button>
        <nav
          ref={dropdownRef}
          className={`drop-menu ${isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
        >
          <ul>
          {brand.map((i) => (<li key={nanoid()} type = 'brand' value={i} onClick = {(e) => brandChange(e)}>{i}</li>))}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default DropDownBrand;

and here the second

```
    const DropDownCategory = () => {
  const { category } = useDropDownLogic()
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectOutsideClick(dropdownRef, false);
  const onClick = () => setIsActive(!isActive)

console.log(category);
  return (
    <div id="dropcategory">
      <div className="menu-container menu-brand">
        <label className = 'nav-label'>Select a Brand</label>
        <button onClick={onClick} className="menu-trigger brand-btn">
        <i className="fas fa-chevron-down fa-2x drop-arrow"></i>
        </button>
        <nav
          ref={dropdownRef}
          className={`drop-menu ${isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
        >
          <ul>
          {category.map((i) => (<li key={nanoid()} type = 'category'>{i}</li>))}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDownCategory;
```

Basically I'm able to populate the first dropdown but not the second. I don't understand why the category  state is not update into the DropDownCategory component

any hint in what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see,

I'm changing the approach. Moving state to a parent component and passing down function to handle click event. Then on Parent I'll update the dstate and pass it as props down to the child.
Nyhting to share yet but it will come

Answer (score 0):

There is no persisted state in a hook, it's a way to share logic and functions.  Because you are defining

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState([])
```

inside of the hook, it is defined each time you call the hook. In your case, dropdowncategory and dropdownbrand each have their personal state variable called category.

To solve this, define [category, setCategory] inside of the menu context, (or any other context) and pull in the values into your hook.. That way all instances of useDropDownLogic() are associated to global context value.

Comment: What if.I move the state in a parent component and share changing state bu props with children? If follow your suggestion instead do I have to update brand and category state by passing in it to context from each child? Which is the best choice?

Comment: Sure, that should work fine. If you are only drilling down one level thats what i would do too. If you have to prop drill 2-5 levels deep, or are sharing the data farther away on the DOM tree, using a hook with context state is a lot easier to reason with.

In my suggestion, you define the state in context, import it once into the hook. Then  use the hook in each component as you are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks.it is definitly the way to go. I already omplemented it also becouse I have to go 2level deeper. Many thanks again